# Retrieve SHMPGSZ on AIX programmatically?

Tags: command, aix

If we execute the command ps -Z on AIX, we get the SHMPGSZ set by the process.
Is there any way to retrieve this information programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Start by using [getprocs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/topic/com.ibm.aix.basetechref/doc/basetrf1/getprocs.htm?resultof=%22getprocs%22%20%22getproc%22%20/%22getprocs%22)

In the procinfo structure (in procinfo.h), there is:

```
char            pi_shm_l2psize;      /* log2 of a proc's shared mem pg sz */
```